# To not return anything if SQL Server CASE value is NULL

Tags: sql-server, function, sql-server-2008, table-valued-parameters

I have a function which returns multiple rows of data with one column based on certain conditions.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetFavoriteFruits]
(   
    @FruitId uniqueidentifier
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    Select Name FROM Fruits WHERE FruitID = @FruitId
    UNION ALL
    Select Name FROM Vegetables WHERE VegetableID = @FruitId
    UNION ALL
    Select
    CASE
    WHEN EXISTS(Select Name FROM Fruits WHERE FruitID = @FruitId) THEN 'Fruit Exists'
    END
    UNION ALL
    Select
    CASE
    WHEN EXISTS(Select Name FROM Vegetables WHERE VegetableID = @FruitId) THEN 'Vegetable Exists'
    END
    UNION ALL
    Select
    CASE
    WHEN EXISTS(Select Name FROM Fruits WHERE FruitID = @FruitId) OR EXISTS(Select Name FROM Vegetables WHERE VegetableID = @FruitId) THEN 'Either Fruit or Vegetable exists'
    END
)
```

When there are values for Fruits and Vegetables in the table, every thing is fine. But if the value for first two cases are not present then the output returned(from last 3 queries) is

```
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

Is there a way I can avoid those NULL and return nothing similar to the first two queries.

Comment: You're UNIONing all the results together, so you could just make what you have into a subquery and then query those results with a where clause to filter out NULLs, there are many better ways, but just to build off what you got...

Comment: @RyanWilson Can you tell me how I can I filter for NULLs with an outer query?

Comment: Posted an answer as an example of how to use outer query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I in no way expect this to be the confirmed answer, I am just posting this to show you an answer to your comment above:

```
 ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetFavoriteFruits]
(   
    @FruitId uniqueidentifier
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT x.Name FROM (
    Select Name FROM Fruits WHERE FruitID = @FruitId
    UNION ALL
    Select Name FROM Vegetables WHERE VegetableID = @FruitId
    UNION ALL
    Select
    CASE
    WHEN EXISTS(Select Name FROM Fruits WHERE FruitID = @FruitId) THEN 'Fruit Exists'
    END
    UNION ALL
    Select
    CASE
    WHEN EXISTS(Select Name FROM Vegetables WHERE VegetableID = @FruitId) THEN 'Vegetable Exists'
    END
    UNION ALL
    Select
    CASE
    WHEN EXISTS(Select Name FROM Fruits WHERE FruitID = @FruitId) OR EXISTS(Select Name FROM Vegetables WHERE VegetableID = @FruitId) THEN 'Either Fruit or Vegetable exists'
    END
) ) AS x
WHERE x.Name IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

```
...
SELECT 'Fruit Exists'
WHERE EXISTS(Select 1 FROM Fruits WHERE FruitID = @FruitId)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use COALESCE to replace the NULL value.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Ryan Wilson is correct. There are better ways to do this.

Comment: Plus 1 for you @kalaolani